# Как исключить работу функции при нажатии на стрелки на клавиатуре?

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

Есть функция, которая срабатывает при вводе текста с клавиатуры, но нужно исключить две кнопки "вверх" и "вниз", я уже все перелопатил, но как это сделать так и не нашел.
Может кто знает и поможет?

```
function seach (id) {
        if(id != 'downKey') {
            inProgress = false;
            startFrom = $(id).val();
            $.ajax({ .... })
}

<input type='text' id='key' onkeyup='seach ("#key")'>
```

В общем, это кусок кода, код рабочий, но он срабатывает и на кнопки вверх и вниз, поэтому нажатие на эти кнопки нужно исключить.

Comment: Код Ваш приложите.

Comment: написал код выше

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Как вариант можно навесить листнер на всю страницу. По такому же приципу и с инпутом можно.

```
document.onkeydown = function(e) {
    switch (e.keyCode) {
        case 37:
            alert('left');
            break;
        case 38:
            alert('up');
            break;
        case 39:
            alert('right');
            break;
        case 40:
            alert('down');
            break;
    }
};
```

http://jsfiddle.net/angusgrant/E3tE6/

Comment: При одинаковых действиях в `case`, отличающихся лишь значением, имеет смысл заменять весь `switch` на обычную хеш-таблицу: [пример](http://jsfiddle.net/Regent3000/E3tE6/209/).

Comment: @Regent, тогда уж и объект вынести, чтобы каждый раз не создавать

Comment: @Grundy это да, но я не стал переусложнять код, показав лишь саму идею.